# What is the general way to find space complexity of recursive algorithms?

Tags: c#, algorithm, big-o

```
int factorial(int n)
{
    if(n < 0)  {return -1;}
    if(n == 0) {return  1;}
    return n*factorial(n-1);
}
```

To find the time complexity I create a recurrence relation

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + c = T(n-2) + 2c = ... = T(n-k) + kc => O(n)
T(0) = 1;
```

What is the general way to find space complexity for that kind of algorithms (like Fibonacci)? We need to find a deep of the call stack?

Comment: Well you will have to recursively call it n times, each call will allocate its own  frame on stack with local variables, so space complexity is order of n.

Comment: Every call to `factorial` function will create a stack frame in the "Stack" portion of the memory for that call. A single stack frame will contain the variables defined in this function, the parameters in the function and the return address. In this case for every call, storing this information can be done in constant time. Since, there will be a linear number of calls to this function, the total memory will be O(n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space required by a recursive algorithm can be approximated by three elements. Space required to store

- recursive stack
- parameters you feed into the function
- output of a function

In example of a factorial. Recursive formula is `T(n) = T(n-1) + c`. When unrolling it you get `T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + ... + n c`. So recursive stack requires `O(n)` space.

Output of a function will be `n!`, to store a number `n`, you need log(n) bits. So to store the result you need `log(n!) = O(n log n)` space.

At each step of your recursion you need to store 1 parameter (`n`). You will need to store it `n` times, and each parameter takes `log(n)` space. So in total `O(nlogn)`

So you ended up with `O(n) + O(nlogn) + O(nlogn) = O(nlogn)`. This is how much space required to calculate your recursion of factorial.

---

Doing this analysis, you can find why exactly chess programs that do alpa-beta pruning requires a lot of ram to calculate positions properly.

Comment: I understood your explanation but why everyone else said that space complexity is O(n)?

Comment: @ivan_petrushenko ask them how much space will it take to store a number `n!`. Let's pick a small number `n`, like 5000. Will they say it is `O(1)`?

Comment: True. For large values of `n`, the space complexity will not be linear and same will go for time complexity (I guess) because then **multiplying two very large numbers cannot be considered a constant time operation** in `return n*factorial(n-1)`. I wrote `O(n)` because i took for granted that since OP is using `int` then it cannot store numbers greater than `19!`.

Answer (score 0):

After writing time complexity in forms like this

T(n) = T(n - 1) + n

or

T(n) = 2T(n/2) + nlogn

and so on.

You have two options:

1) Use repeated substitution method which is needs some math skills for some cases because you should follow the steps until T(1) or T(0) and then calculate a summation.

or

2) Use the master Theorem which is like a formula [Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem), and works for many practical cases